# Can someone help me with this example?

Tags: java, arrays

I just started to learn about programming in school and I was stuck on one of the problems.
I know this is way too easy but I do not get any of this.
I get the creating the class and constructing to the class that takes a single argument of type int array(I think) but I do not get the method part.
Also if you guys do not want to provide an example, can you at least give me clear definition of constructor and method because I could not understand what it was saying in java tutorial cites.

here is my work so far:

```
private int[] members;
    public Lesson3(int[] array1){
    this.members= array1;   
    }
```

and here is the task I was suppose to do it:

Create a class called GiveMeNext. Add a constructor to the class that takes a single argument of type int array.  Store the int array in a member variable on the class.
Add a member method to the class called getNextGreaterThan that has a single int parameter and returns an int.

Comment: You should research a little bit more and at least see the basics tutorials of java programming.

Comment: take a look at this example in Java Tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Just trying help . please do comment if theres something wrong with my answer :)

```
public class GiveMeNext {

    // this is the member variable of the class marked as a private.
    // it is accessible only inside this class. 
    private int[] someArray;

    // this is your default Constructor.
    public GiveMeNext(){

    }

    // This is the constructor with a parameter.
    // Constructor  doesnt contain any return type 
    // You can create multiple Constructor in this class but ofcourse with diff parameter.
    public GiveMeNext(int[] someArray){
        this.someArray = someArray;
    }


    //this is the method getNextGreaterThan.
    // the 'int' after public is what we called return type.
    // the 'int someInt' is what we called parameter.
    // the return someInt is used to return the value of 'someInt'.
    public int getNextGreaterThan(int someInt){
        return someInt;
    }
}
```

for more info look at these reference/tutorials :

[Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

[Understanding Constructor](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html)

[Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

[Understanding Methods](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_methods.html)